# number is missing decimal

Tags: php, json

I have some numbers in PHP : 19,6, 33,33, 5,5

I want to get 1,196, 1,333 and 1,055.

```
(19.6 / 100) + 1 = 1.196

(33.33 / 100) + 1 = 1.333

(5.5 / 100) + 1 = 1.055
```

I have this value,

```
$item['tva'] = 1 + ($tvas[$tmpItem] / 100);
```

And in JSON I'm getting 1.19 not 1.196 why ?

Comment: And you're using periods not commas, as the seperator ?

Comment: Can you please check your numbers? Please fix your question so that we can answer

Comment: $tvas = $_POST['cmdTva'] = 19,6, 33,33, 5,5 etc... i received my post with commas

Answer (score 1):

I made an working example.

```
// array with numbers to add
$numbers = array(19.6, 33.33, 5.5);

// array to put formatted numbers in
$result = null;

foreach ($numbers as $i => $number) {
     // format number to have 3 decimal values and push to result array
     $result[$i] = number_format(1 + ($number / 100.), 3);
}

// decode array to json and force keys
print json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

This gives:

```
{"0":"1.196","1":"1.333","2":"1.055"}
```